# Installing package locally in node_module bin on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

I'm building in my package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "all": "npm run build && npm run postbuild",
    "build": "npx @11ty/eleventy",
    "postbuild": "npx pagefind --source _site"
  },
```

and then `npm run all --serve`

But please note that when I'm doing this locally, in dev mode, by running command in Windows Power Shell `npx pagefind --source _site` does not work (I think it's a problem of this pagefind library).

So I'm thinking to run directly the executable node_modules/pagefind/bin/pagefind_extended (locally in bin) like this:

```
npx run node_modules/pagefind/bin/pagefind_extended
```

and in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx @11ty/eleventy && npx pagefind --source _site",
    "build": "npx @11ty/eleventy",
    "postbuild": "npx pagefind --source _site"
  },
```

and then run

`npm run dev` (when I want to run it locally in dev mode);

and

`npm run build && npm run postbuild` (in production on Cloudflare Pages)

Please, is this the best way to proceed? What would you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use `npx` when packages are installed locally. `pagefind` should be enough

Comment: You mean just use "postbuild": "pagefind --source _site"? But what about the rest, do you tinik it's the best way to proceed?

Comment: I don't understand your issue, but afaik `postbuild` should run automatically when you run `build`